# Is there a good place for human help identifying parts?

Tags: components

I have a part that I have not seen before, and that has no identifying information on it that I'm trying to replace in a piece of critical equipment.  Being a semi-common design, and being a non-semiconductor, I thought it would be fairly easy to find (it's a stacked USB-A to through-hole connector), but because of a unique stair-step outline at the rear of the part, it turns out to not be very common.  I have been over and over the common distributor sites (Digikey, Mouser, Allied, Newark) but can't find a replacement.

Is there a place on the web, maybe not here, but maybe a related stack exchange, or another site, where one could find assistance from other people with potentially identifying unknown components by image alone?

[image]

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic.  But you might try some distributors.  In the USA there are companies like Digi-Key, Newark, Mouser among others.

Comment: There is a small chance that it is custom, but whether custom or not, you may be able to get a replacement from the equipment manufacturer.

Comment: Look very carefully for any markings that would indicate the manufacturer, which could greatly narrow your search.

Comment: Also search for whatever product you removed it from- since connectors are frequently damaged by users there may be others who have tracked down one or more sources.

Comment: jwh20: I have checked all major distributors.  Peter Bennett, that's a great idea, and I did call them, but they said they couldn't/wouldn't tell me what it was, and can't send individual parts. (!)  Elliot Alderson, I did look all over it with a magnifying glass, and much to my surprise, there isn't a single marking on it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even sans information on the application, a quick search yields this obsolete part number (3–1734062–2):

[image]

The key word along with your verbal description is "offset" type.

While it's possible there are compatible versions from other manufacturers, it's also quite possible there are no current manufacturers of this part.

Comment: Thanks for your help in locating this.  I even saw this document from TE as well, but breezed right over the pages because of the "obsolete" marking.  It doesn't sound like there is anywhere anyone knows of specifically to ask for help with part identification like this.  That said, I do appreciate your assistance.  Perhaps I am out of luck.  Seems odd that such a once popular part has been discontinued.

Comment: One has to be very careful when specifying parts designed for much larger and more fickle markets. On one project, the client insisted on using a special connector with interleaved grounds that was created for a specific HDD interface. Perfect technically for the application and very inexpensive and  because of piggybacking on the high consumer volumes. The life cycle of such a part is measured in months and they ended up having to do a lifetime buy of the components.

Comment: P.S. In this case there probably were other makers of a compatible part because the drawing differs in small likely unimportant (and un-dimensioned) details from your photo.